# Pushnotification provisioning certificate issue in my certificates

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, ssl-certificate, provisioning

I need to enable push notification services for my app.When i followed this link https://www.parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications 
 it makes me to download provisioning certificate from my developer program id.

I followed each and every step to download it.But when i try to install it on keychain access it shows error as "key chain warning The “System Roots” keychain cannot be modified"..When i try to google it the issue which i'm facing it leads to download developer certificate and WWDRCA certificate.I dont know where to get it.

And my certificate looks like the image below

[image]

Can any one help please?..Is there any tutorial helping from basic step by step to get it done which includes developer certificate and WWDRCA certificate..

And another question is what is the purpose of developer certificate and WWDRCA certificate?...How it helps to push notification provisioning certificate...

Answer (score 1):

you can download all the certificate from the Apple developer portal. Everything is explained there step-by-step. You have to have the developer account activated before you can proceed.